# How to create histogram on values not on counts using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to create a histogram using Python and Matplotlib from the values in an array not on the count of the values in the array.
For example:-

`X = [0,0,0,1,10,5,0,0,5]`

If I use the below code

`n, bins, patches = plt.hist(X)
plt.show()`

[I get this histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBFBL.png)

This is counting the number of occurrences and creating the histogram.
The output should be like this:-
[Expected Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr1YO.png)

Comment: Can you add an image showing what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: Did you look at the docs?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you want a bar graph rather than a histogram. Note that a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) is:

> An accurate representation of the distribution of numerical data

It differs from a bar graph, in the sense that a bar graph relates two variables, but a histogram relates only one.
For plotting a bar graph you could use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html):

```
X = [0,0,0,1,10,5,0,0,5]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.bar(range(len(X)), X)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


vector_of_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
plt.hist(vector_of_values)

plt.show()
```

if you want more bins you can replace

```
plt.hist(vector_of_values)
```

with

```
plt.hist(vector_of_values, bins=100) # or any number of bins you can have
```